# Open About Dialog after onClickEvent in Settings Menu

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog

I'm trying to open an About Dialog (extends from DialogFragment) after clicking on a Settings "About" button.

This is my about class

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class AboutDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.about_message)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Do i need to add it to the manifest, ? i believe i shouldn't

This is my SettingsActivity which currently works perfectly

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.*;
import android.preference.*;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

     public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        }
    }


}
```

How do i make a call of this dialog from the SettingsActivity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to simply call your `DialogFragment` you can use the following

```
    AboutDialog newFragment = new AboutDialog();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

There are details example in developer site. Please see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for detail info

**N.B.** `DialogFragment` is available only in api level 11 or higher. So if you use it in lower api there will be error. In that case use [SupportLibrary](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Comment: Great, but where do i add this piece of code for the dialog? How to know when the About button was pressed in this case inside the SettingsACtivity? Thanks for your reply